# Attribute error : 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I've been working on a project lately and got the above error. It says " Error during template rendering".I have a similar model, which works perfectly fine. I've looked for similar errors but got none matching my situation. I don't know where I went wrong. It would be great if I get helpful answers.

**Models.py**

```
class ServiceTax(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="service_tax",null=True,blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    percent=models.FloatField(default='0')
    add_amount=models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ServiceTaxForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ServiceTax
    fields = "__all__"
    widgets = {
        'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'percent' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','step':'0.01'}),
        'add_amount' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','maxlength':5}),


    }
    labels={
        'add_amount': "Additional Amount"
    }
```

**Views.py**

```
def tax_form(request,id=0):
if request.method == 'GET':
    if id == 0:
        form = ServiceTaxForm(request)
    else:

        tax = ServiceTax.objects.get(pk=id)
        if tax in request.user.service_tax.all():
            form = ServiceTaxForm(request,instance=tax)
        else:
            return redirect('/revenue/tax')
    return render(request,'tax-form.html',{'form':form})
else:
    if id==0:
        form = ServiceTaxForm(request,request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():



            name = form.cleaned_data["name"]

            percent = form.cleaned_data["percent"]
            add_amount = form.cleaned_data["add_amount"]




            t = AnnualTax(
                name=name,
                percent=percent,
                add_amount=add_amount,

                )

            t.save()
            request.user.service_tax.add(t)
    else:

        tax = ServiceTax.objects.get(pk=id)
        if tax in request.user.service_tax.all():
            form = ServiceTaxForm(request,request.POST,instance=tax)
            if form.is_valid():

                name = form.cleaned_data["name"]

                percent = form.cleaned_data["percent"]
                add_amount = form.cleaned_data["add_amount"]



                tax_obj = ServiceTax.objects.get(pk=id)
                tax_obj.name = name


                tax_obj.percent = percent
                tax_obj.add_amount = add_amount

                tax_obj.save()


    return redirect('/revenue/tax')
```

**tax-form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<a href="{% url 'tax_list' %}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-3x m-2"></i></a>
<div class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Add Service Tax</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    {{ form.name | as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    {{ form.percent | as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    {{ form.add_amount | as_crispy_field}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-fill pull-right">
                            {% if request.get_full_path == '/income/tax/add/' %}
                            Add Tax
                            {% else %}
                            Update
                            {% endif %}
                        </button>



                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve your forms passing **request.METHOD**, not just request

As an example this piece of code `form = ServiceTaxForm(request)` should be `form = ServiceTaxForm(request.POST)`

Comment: Yay! It worked. But for the similar model, I didn't pass it as request.POST, But still it's working! Can I get an explanation?

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but thats weird cuz request itself does not have a get method. I can think two options: 

Either the code is not being executed, or something like request = request.POST was made before.

If u want more infos about it, you can find here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/